# Pool Cloud SQL PostgreSQL connections using PgBouncer

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, connection-pooling, pgbouncer, cloud-sql-proxy

We are new to Google Cloud SQL and have been trying to integrate pgbouncer with Google Cloud SQl Postgres and authenticate database users with SECURITY DEFINER function (which queries pg_shadow)

**Our Configuration:**

- Server -> Pgbouncer + Cloud sql proxy (side car) -> Cloud SQL Postgres

**Problem:**

- But as cloud sql postgres actually does not allow to read pg_shadow from a privileged user (i.e postgres user is not a superuser). This makes it impossible to setup pgbouncer with SECURITY DEFINER function.
- Cloud SQL doesn't provide customers to use superuser *(cloudsqladmin)*

We've read through many articles (mostly cloud-proxy issues) where they have suggested to use pgbouncer but have not elaborated on the above problem.

**Options not applicable:**

- Application level pooling (not feasible right now for us)
- Authenticating using auth_file eg. users_list.txt (not recomended, needs manual management of database users)

**What we are looking for:**

- We intend to run a single instance of cloudsql-proxy and pgbouncer which proxies and pools connections to cloudsql postgres database.

We would appreciate your help guys!

Comment: Responding on the GitHub issue: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/issues/1099.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @CengizCan the question has been answered by enocom. You can refer to whole discussion in the link (GitHub issue) provided above in the comment (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/issues/1099). Thank You.